# Delete folder based on date in folder name YYYYmmdd

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to work out how to have a script automatically delete a folder based on a date within the folder's name if the folder's name date is OVER 6 years. (Windows)

Folder name format YYYYmmdd

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What specific issues are you having?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be done they way you ask, based on the date in the name.

But in case you can use one based on the last modified date it would be like this:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\route" /m * /s /d -2190 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

2190 would be 6 years in days

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to match the folder name, convert it to a date and compare.

This is a contrived example but you might get the idea from that.

```
# Get all of the folders
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory

# Loop through the folders and validate the date prefix
$folders | ForEach-Object {
    # The replace converts the prefix into a valid dateTime format for comparison
    # \d  - matches a digit
    # {n} - matches the previous token exactly n times
    $datePrefix = $_.name -replace '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3'

    # If the folder name prefix is older than 6 years then it's okay to delete
    if ([datetime]$datePrefix -gt (Get-Date).AddYears(-6)) {
        '{0}: Folder is older than 6 years. Okay to delete' -f $_.Name
    }
}
```